# Accessing Multiple QB Companies

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have a client with 5 stores set up as 5 companies in QB Enterprise.  I have been asked to write a program (C# MVC) which includes the ability to transfer inventory between stores.  This would require access to more than one store (QB Company).

I'm struggling with how to provide this, since the QBFC connection to a running copy of QB isn't going to let me access all the stores readily.  While it would be possible to switch to access Store #2 (I think), I will have other computers still accessing store #1.

Is there a way for my program to access all 5 stores?  I would like to have one site running and serving all the stores.

If I'm out to lunch (and out of luck), any better ideas?

Comment: Changing companies would work if I only had on user running the system.  I expect to have 3-5 workstations active at each store.  Switching companies on the connected QB would cause problems with other sessions attempting to access their company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access individual QB company files by specifying the company file when you first connect.

However, you can only have one open at a time and the UI can not be open to another QB company file when you are trying to do this on that system.

Comment: You could queue up the decrements/increments for each company, and then process them whenever the right company file connects.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a QB file and extract data from it and then open a different QB file and import the data. We have 2 programs that work in this manner.